# How to pass an object with an object parameter to a celery task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

I have an object `model_test_api` which is new by as following.

```
import test_script
model_test_api = test_script.TestAPI(api)
```

the `api` which requires to new `TestAPI` is also an object.

```
import model_api
api = model_api.Model_API()
```

I am trying the following [two methods](http://%5Benter%20link%20description%20here%5D%5B1%5D) to pass `model_test_api` to a `celery` task.

```
1. another_function.apply_async(model_test_api)
2. another_function.apply_async(lambda: test_script.TestAPI(api))
```

However, both of them gave me an error`kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable`. Then I am packing  `model_test_api` to a json object.

```
import json
json_test_api = json.dumps(model_test_api.__dict__)
another_function.apply_async(json_test_api)
```

It gives me another error `TypeError: Object of type Model_API is not JSON serializable`. Anyone has an idea of what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *everything is an object in python*. You *are* passing it, but as the error message clearly states, you are passing something that is not JSON serializable, which presumably, is required.

Comment: The error message tells us something your description didn't: that you're trying to create JSON.  HOWEVER, only your example 2 is passing a function.  Example 1 is passing an object.  However, objects can't be converted to JSON either.  Where did you get the code you're trying to run?

Comment: Thanks@TimRoberts here `another_function` descripted here is a distributed function by `celery`.

Comment: What does `TestAPI(api)` return ? Is it really an object constructor or a decorator ?

Comment: It returns an object@Kris

Comment: @jasonshu **everything is an object**. Saying "it returns an object" **doesn't tell us anything**.

Comment: What does `type(model_test_api)` tell ?

Comment: @Kris `<class 'test_script.TestAPI'>`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yeah, what I am trying to demonstrate is `model_test_api ` is not a common type(dict, list...)

Answer (score 1):

Gonna cover a few things before getting stuck in with answer, so celery enables event streaming for python. You have a database which contains a `queue` of tasks that need processing, normally this db is `postgres` or `redis`. There are workers that are watching the queue and when something gets added to the queue a worker on the network with available processing resource picks the task up, performs the processing and then that task is marked as completed.

So when you trigger the line `another_function.apply_async` that means the task called `another_function` is added to the queue and any parameter  values that are passed in are as well. This means that all parameters need to be serialised in order to be stored in the database `postgres` or `redis`. Celery cannot store in memory python objects in a queue because it could be a completely different machine that performs the processing and it will not have the object in its RAM.

I will give an example of recommended implementation, say you have a model called `CIA_Agent_Model` and it has three attributes a primary key and some text fields. You have a celery task called `another_function` and you want to pass in the `CIA_Agent_Model` instance, you would call the celery task using `another_function.delay(agent_model_instance.id)` where the parameter being passed in is the primary key of the object rather than the object itself. Then inside the celery task you get the object via the ID again from your database. You can also serialise the model instance https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/ and the result of serialisation can be passed into `another_function.delay(model_serialisation_result)`.

You can create a custom function that converts the returned object of `test_script.TestAPI(api)` to a json dict and then pass that json dict into a celery task call parameter.